# How to create a common function for all forms using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to call a single function from all forms. In vb.net there is an option module. In this module we can create functions/variables and we call them from anywhere in the project. Is there any option in C# like this module? 
Finally, if I need to use a single function in my entire project, is this possible or not?

Comment: create a class and declare the function there .. where ever you want to implement just make the object and call the function.

Comment: If your entire project needs only one namespace, put a class in that namespace, make the function static, and call it with `SampleClass.MyStaticFuncion()`.

Comment: yes this is possible.  If you make this function [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) you don't need an instance of the class that owns the function.

Comment: thank you thanks a lot for all replies.i got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for a *static class*?

```
 namespace MyNamespace {
   ...
   public static class MyStaticClass {
     public static int MyFunc(int x) {
       return x * 2;
     } 
   }
   ...
 }
```

And you can call it

```
 using MyNamespace;

 ...

 int result = MyStaticClass.MyFunc(123);
```

you may want to add *static import* in order to get rid of `MyStaticClass`:

```
 using static MyNamespace.MyStaticClass;

 ...

 // Just "MyFunc", no need to the class name being mentioned 
 int result = MyFunc(123);
```